# Flutter NodeJS Authorization Issue

Tags: node.js, flutter

I'm new flutter and nodejs.

I wrote the API with nodejs to save people to MongoDB database.
So I successfully working with sign-login process users saved database.

But in the some point I want to change and update some data, for example user balance.
So I write below function for the flutter:

```
  static Future<BalanceUpdateResponseModel> update(
      BalanceUpdateRequestModel model) async {
    // var loginDetails = await SharedService.loginDetails();

    Map<String, String> requestHeaders = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      // 'Authorization': 'Basic ${loginDetails!.data.token}'
    };
    var url = Uri.http(Config.apiURL, Config.updateBalanceAPI);
    print(url);
    var response = await client.post(
      url,
      headers: requestHeaders,
      body: jsonEncode(model.toJson()),
    );
    print(balanceResponseJson(response.body));
    return balanceResponseJson(response.body);
  }
```

But when I want to use this function I get unauthorized user.
But before, user login and authorized.

I call the update function in below:

```
var loginDetails = await SharedService.loginDetails();
username = loginDetails?.data.username;
// password = loginDetails?.data.password;
email = loginDetails?.data.email;
balance = loginDetails?.data.balance;
print("before balance: ");
print(balance);
updatedBalance = (balance! - 5);

BalanceUpdateRequestModel model = BalanceUpdateRequestModel(
  username: username!,
  email: email!,
  balance: updatedBalance,
);
APIService.update(model).then((response) {
  if (response.data != null) {
    print("current balance");
    print(balance);
  }
});
```

Whe I try to send post update method with Postman after the authorized user, everything working correctly. But when I try to send post request with flutter I get unauthorized although user authorized.

I write service functions like in links https://github.com/SnippetCoders/flutter_nodejs_jwt_login_register/blob/main/services/user.services.js

How can I solve the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Authorization` header is commented out and specifies `Basic` authentication:

```dart
      // 'Authorization': 'Basic ${loginDetails!.data.token}'
```

But with tokens, it is usually `Bearer` authentication that is used:

```dart
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ${loginDetails!.data.token}'
```

Comment: I just realized that I have to send tokens in every request when I send, thank you. It works now. So how do you think my update function is written properly? Because I'm very new about this subject

Comment: As a beginner it is more important to get things working and probably easier for you to explicitly send the token with every request. But when you gain more experience you might want to use https://pub.dev/packages/dio and an interceptor that adds the token to each request for you.